# A newbie has a question about data frame column names

Tags: r

I'm new to R and I learnt data.frame today.
I want to use the first row of my data frame as the column names, but the column names became really wired. Here is a sample of my data:

```
a <- data.frame(V1 = c("ENSMUSG00000000001_Gnai3", "0.00"), V2 = c("ENSMUSG00000000003_Pbsn", "0.00"), row.names = c("Gene_id", "P1-3-A1"))
a
```

The outcome is:[outcome_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOlUP.png)

I want to give the first row as my column names, so I type:

```
colnames(a) <- a[1,]
```

But the column names become like this:[outcome_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsPdq.png)

When I call the column name by using:
`colnames(a)`
,I got this: "2" "2", instead of "ENSMUSG00000000001_Gnai3", "ENSMUSG00000000003_Pbsn"

Comment: `names(a) <- unlist(a[1,])` will do the naming as you want (`names` and `colnames` do the same thing here), but instead of fixing this symptom, I suggest you fix your import code. If you're using `read.table`, then use `read.table(..., header = TRUE)`. (Why? None of your columns will be `numeric` or `integer` or anything other than `character`. While it's not difficult to correct this, there is the chance that these efforts might miss something that should have been done correctly the first time.)

Comment: (And I say that under the assumption that you are not really using `data.frame`, instead you're reading it in somehow. If you really are using `data.frame` to do this, then ... my comment fixes your immediate symptom, good luck with the rest of your data analysis!)

Comment: thanks, r2evans. The unlisted() function helps me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. How did you import the data? You should be able to fix this while importing the data itself. Maybe adding `header = TRUE` would be enough.
2. While importing use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` which will avoid turning string value to factors.
3. Finally if you can't do anything in step 1 and 2 here's a way which can fix the data in your current setup.

```
#Assign column names
colnames(a) <- as.character(unlist(a[1,]))
#Remove 1st row
a <- a[-1, ]
#Change to respective classes
a <- type.convert(a)
```